# Print TABLE TYPE parameter in Stored Procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I need to pass a JSON response from an API to a Stored Procedure.  So, I created a TABLE TYPE and tried using it in the procedure. But I get an error

> Must declare the scalar variable "@mydata".

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[apidata] AS TABLE (
    [response] [nvarchar](max) NULL
)

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_API] (
    @mydata dbo.apidata READONLY
)
AS
BEGIN
    PRINT @mydata
END
GO
```

Comment: You can't print a table variable. But you can select from it, like: `select * From @mydata`. Btw, you could also pass the JSON as is and shred it with OPENJSON.

Comment: @siggemannen Spot on! It worked. Please post it as an answer.

Comment: I wonder if the OP *is* passing the json response verbatim given the table-type is a single nvarchar(max) column, if so it should be a scalar type anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't print a table variable, only scalar expressions, that's why SQL Server tells you it can't find the scalar variable.

But you can select from it and work with it like a regular table:

```sql
select * From @mydata
```

Btw, you could also pass the JSON as a string and shred it with OPENJSON.